# Problems after uninstalling evolution app

Tags: evolution, gnome-calendar

I installed the Evolution app in my system. After uninstalling it, after some time a gnome pop-up window appears on my screen. This is annoying and I want to stop it. Please help me.

[image: Screenshot]

I installed it by using this command:
`sudo apt install evolution` and uninstalled it by using this command:
`sudo apt autoremove evolution`

Comment: How, exactly, did you uninstall Evolution? Please review your history and logs and provide the complete, exact commands you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "Online accounts" (in "Settings) and re-add your google account there.